# Memory leak detection with boost::test

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, boost-test

I try to enable msvc memory leak detection with line number like this snippet I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
C:\PROGRAM FILES\VISUAL STUDIO\MyProjects\leaktest\leaktest.cpp(20) : {18} 
normal block at 0x00780E80, 64 bytes long.
 Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
Object dump complete.
```

I tried to set the preprocessor define

> _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

manually in the project properties but I only get this:

```
Dumping objects ->
{1466} normal block at 0x00BD4DD0, 40 bytes long.
 Data: <(o;   ; (o;   1 > 28 6F 3B 00 90 A9 3B 00 28 6F 3B 00 00 D6 31 10
```

without line numbers. I also tried to manually define main by using BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN and dump by myself like this:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int res = ::boost::unit_test::unit_test_main( &init_function, argc, argv );  
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return res;
}
```

But also without any success. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Boost.Test you can use --detect_memory_leaks="allocation number"

Answer (score 4):

In MSVC you can set a breakpoint to the allocation number 1466, in the code:

```
  _crtBreakAlloc = 1466
```

or in the Watch window you can add `_crtBreakAlloc` and value 1466 once the application started (of course you need a breakpoint in the main function). [More details on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the debugger! For example, with help of deleaker can select the stack to see where memory was allocated